# Ubuntu accepts ssh connection when it should reject it (wrong IP for the interface)

Tags: networking

EXECUTIVE SUMMARY

My Ubuntu VM (hostname fubar) is making the ip address (eth0 169.254.32.15) of one interface visible to hosts reachable by another interface (eth1 10.3.17.129/23).

I want "ssh user@169.254.32.15" from machines on the 10.3.16.0/23 to not connect to fubar.

DETAILS

the interfaces on my Ubuntu VM:

```
root@fubar:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4e:12:0f:0b:48:91  
      inet addr:169.254.32.15  Bcast:169.254.63.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4c12:fff:fe0b:4891/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 92:fe:57:11:bd:6c  
      inet addr:10.3.17.129  Bcast:10.3.17.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::90fe:57ff:fe11:bd6c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2471362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:71144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:337482223 (337.4 MB)  TX bytes:5136143 (5.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)

root@fubar:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.16.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.3.16.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
root@fubar:~# uname -a
Linux fubar 3.19.0-80-generic #88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@fubar:~# netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5617            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 169.254.32.15:5617      10.3.17.28:50841        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.3.17.129:5617        10.3.16.65:38753        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::5617                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9797            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::1269                 :::*
```

eth1 is intended to be externally facing.  Eth0 is connected to another VM (and nothing else) via a virtual bridge.

The undesired behavior is that when I ssh from another VM (10.3.17.28) to 169.254.32.15 it successfully connects to fubar (see netstat output above).  How can I stop this from happening?

Interface stats show the packets for this SSH are actually going over eth1.  Obviously fubar is making 169.254.32.15 visible to the 10.3.16/23 network but I don't know why.

Why is this happening? How can I stop it from happening?

EDIT1: iptables data collected as requested

```
root@fubar:~# iptables -v -x -n -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
root@fubar:~# iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L 
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
root@fubar:~#
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the outputs for `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`.

Comment: it looks like iptables is not installed.

fubar# iptables
-bash: iptables: command not found

There are headerfiles for iptables but no exec:

fubar# find / -iname iptables\*
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-33-generic/include/config/ip/nf/iptables.h
...
should I install iptables or is the absence of the executable imply there is nothing to see here?

edit: I installed iptables and collected the data

Comment: Perhaps you should figure out why eth0 has a [link-local IPv4 address](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/) instead of an actual useful IP address. Myself, I'd just block the entire sub-net from the INPUT chain in iptables.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your question that sshd is listening on all interfaces on port TCP/5617. So I would recommend editing your /etc/ssh/sshd_config. SSHD can be configured to listen on specific IP addresses, which if they are static you can hard code into your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. If there's a line that reads

```
listenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

change it to the below. If it doesn't exist just add the below:

```
listenAddress 10.3.17.129
```

If you're using ipv6, you might want to also change

```
ListenAddress ::
```

to

```
ListenAddress fe80::90fe:57ff:fe11:bd6c
```

However, if this server is configured for DHCP and you prefer it that way, then I would probably resort to iptables as Doug recommended. There are a couple ways to accomplish that depending on what you actually want to block.

If you want to block ssh coming from the 10.3.16.0/23 network into the eth0 interface (change REJECT to DROP if you're worried about esoteric attacks/scans, otherwise REJECT fails faster):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5617 -s 10.3.16.0/23 -j REJECT
```

If you want to block all traffic from this network coming into this interface:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.3.16.0/23 -j REJECT
```

Once you add the rule of your choosing, test to make sure it's having the desired effect, if it is, make it permanent with:

```
service iptables save
```

That command may vary depending on what version of Ubuntu you're running.

I still don't know why this would be happening without deeper troubleshooting, I would suggest checking the output of

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

And making sure it's zero, unless you intend for this VM to be routing between these networks. To fix that, add the following line to the bottom of /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```